# Birational self-maps of spheres

Tags: rational-functions, automorphism-group, birational-geometry

What can be said about rational maps $S^2\to S^2$, $S^3\to S^3$, etc, which are invertible and have rational inverses?  (Here, $S^n$ denotes the subset $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:|x|=1\}$.)

I know that $\pi_n(S^n)$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, and I suspect that this implies that the only injective maps $S^n\to S^n$ are homotopic to the identity function.

I have also run across the notion of Cremona groups, but have not been able to fruitfully use this information.  For example, the map $[x:y:z]\mapsto[y^2+z^2:xy:xz]$ is a beautiful involution of $P(\mathbb{R}^2)$, but I don't know if this can be modified to be a map $S^2\to S^2$.  (In particular, I would like a version of the map which extends to a map of the balls bounded by $S^2$.)

Any reference which considers this question or states that this question is open or hard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you mean to regard $S^2=\mathbb{P}^1$ as a complex manifold/algebraic curve, then it is well known that rational maps of Riemann surfaces can be completed to bona fide holomorphic maps. So, such a rational map with rational inverse is actually an automorphism of $\Bbb{P}^1$. Such maps are given by $\operatorname{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: Does this work for $S^3$ and higher?

Comment: You should be careful what you mean by rational maps in that case. $S^3$ does not have a structure of a complex manifold (or complex algebraic variety) so you would need to think about real algebraic geometry. Anyway, the phenomenon of rational maps being regular maps is a dimension $1$ phenomenon in algebraic geometry. In higher dimensions the situation becomes much more complicated. Maybe you should explain what notion of rational maps you are considering.

Comment: I had in mind a function like $f(x,y,z)=(f_1(x,y,z),f_2(x,y,z),f_3(x,y,z))$ where each $f_i$ is a rational function, and $|f(x,y,z)|=1$ whenever $|(x,y,z)|=1$.